# Windows Forms Themes

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use different themes for my form. How can I use them in my form?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: theming may be painful with winforms. Can you move to WPF or SilverLight ?

Answer (score 1):

Winforms generally isn't easily stylable. If you're after this sort of functionality it'd be much easier to use WPF.

Answer (score 1):

You could use third party controls like Infragistics or Telerik to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian said is not a built-in functionality of Windows Forms, it's built-in in WPF.

For windows forms I would suggest using 3rd party libraries, like DevExpress or Telerik, used both, I prefer DevExpress far more ;-)